# Transpose multiple key-value pairs in single rows to multiple rows

Tags: excel

This seems like a foolishly simple thing to do but I've been struggling with figuring out a way to do it functionally.

I have data in Excel in this format:

```
1 a b
2 c
3 a c d
```

And would like to look like so:

```
1 a
1 b
2 c
3 a
3 c 
3 d
```

Comment: The [Get and Transform](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-unpivot-data-in-excel#:~:text=Unpivot%20your%20data,columns%20within%20your%20Excel%20table.) method is an easy method to accomplish an unpivot task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above in comments by **[Isolated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13118009/isolated)**, using `Power Query` will be the **most easiest** way to accomplish unpivoting the data, perhaps if you are using `MS365` you can try using the new dynamic spill array formulas as well.

---

**Using Power Query :**

---

• Select some cell in your **Data Table**,

• **Data Tab** => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the PQ Editor opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the 2 Tables Names,

• Paste the M Code below in place of what you see.

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Datatbl"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

• Change the Table name from **Datatbl** to as **Outputtbl** before importing it back into Excel, note that you need to select from **Home** tab --> **Close & Load** --> **Close & Load To** --> Select either **Existing Worksheet** or **New Worksheet** as per your preferences.

[image]

---

**Output In Excel :**

[image]

---

**Using Excel Formulas --> Exclusively Applicable To MS365**

---

• If you are using **MS365** and when writing if you are in Current Channel then,

```
=LAMBDA(array,
LET(x,IF(array="",NA(),array),
DROP(REDUCE(0,TOCOL(TAKE(x,,1)&"|"&DROP(x,,1),3),
LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,"|")))),1)))(A13:D15)
```

---

• Also Note : You can use a **custom**, **reusable formula** with a **friendly name** by placing the above formula in the **Name Manager** - with **Define Name** as **UNPIVOT**.

So from **Formulas** tab, Click on **Define Name** --> Enter the name as **UNPIVOT** and place the above formula as in refers to, scope will be `Workbook`

```
=LAMBDA(array,
LET(x,IF(array="",NA(),array),
DROP(REDUCE(0,TOCOL(TAKE(x,,1)&"|"&DROP(x,,1),3),
LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,"|")))),1)))
```

---

The Syntax is

```
=UNPIVOT(array)
```

---

Where array is `A13:D15`

---

[image]

---